# on a bungled cue & serene blare

Tags: meaning

> So kill me,” screamed my mother. “You know what you are! You are
>   failure. Failure! You are failure!”
>
> Then there was a sudden, terrific, bursting crash – and after it, as
>   if on a bungled cue, the serene blare of an a capella soprano picking
>   her way down a scale.
>
> From the Water Faucet Vision by Gish Jen

Context: The protagonist's mother and father had a fight. Then her mother fell out of a window. (They were U.S. immigrants)

I originally asked a related question here. https://forum.wordreference.com/thre...#post-18170005

We take "the serene blare of an a capella soprano picking her way down a scale" to mean the writer's mother's screams were going downwards one by one in a scale as the writer's mother fell down.

My question: how do you understand "on a bungled cue"? Was the cue itself wrong? or did the writer's mother bungle the cue (metaphorically)?

How do you understand "serene" and "blare"? They seem to be a contradiction to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. It is sometimes difficult to gather the meaning from literary writing because the author is deliberately communicating subtle details with their word choices. The writing is not straightforward.

I think you're correct about description of the mother's screams going down the scale as she falls. And I also agree that 'serene' and 'blare' are contradictory. A blare is not usually a serene sound. I think this is a case where the writer is conveying something unspoken about the situation by using this unusual word choice. We are surprised by this contradiction so we have to stop and think about it. Objectively, the sound is a blaring sound, but to the narrator it is also serene in some way. Maybe the narrator is relaxing because they know their mother will no longer be telling them they are a failure. Maybe it is such a terrible tragedy that their mother is falling out of the window that they are suddenly removed from the situation emotionally as an unconscious defense against the realization that their mother will be badly hurt. It's hard to say from reading just this small section of the book.

There's a clue to what the bungled cue is in the sentence. The text says, 'and after it, as if on a bungled cue...'. So I think that the scream happens later than would normally be expected. If the scream were on cue we would hear the scream at the same time as the crash, but in this case there's a time gap between them.

Comment: I agree that blaring is an objective description and serene is a subjective one. I  would say that " they are suddenly removed from the situation emotionally as an unconscious defense against the realization that their mother will be badly hurt" would be more likely.   Thanks so much for your well-explained answer. :)